# Oracle LPAD/RPAD function issue in AL32UTF8

Tags: oracle

The NLS_CHARACTERSET is AL23UTF8 in my Oracle database.
I have problem when using the RPAD function:

```
Connected to Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 
Connected as apps@UATSED

SQL> 
SQL> SELECT '甲骨文' ORACLE, LENGTHB('甲骨文') ORACLE_LENGTH,
  2         RPAD('甲骨文', 10, '$') ORA_RPAD, LENGTHB(RPAD('甲骨文', 10, '$')) ORA_RPAD_LENGTH
  3    FROM dual
  4  ;

ORACLE    ORACLE_LENGTH ORA_RPAD      ORA_RPAD_LENGTH
--------- ------------- ------------- ---------------
甲骨文                9 甲骨文$$$$                 13

SQL>
```

We know a Chinese character take 3 bytes in AL32UTF8 encoding method.
Therefore in my example, the lengthb function returns the correct result.
But we I use RPAD function to pad more spaces with $, it took 2 bytes for one Chinese character, not 3 bytes. So when i pad 10 bytes in total, it filled 4 $ signs for me.

My question is why RPAD function don't follow the way like lengthb?

Comment: According [Oracle doc](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions147.htm#SQLRF06103) it should return "甲骨文$$$$$$$": The argument n is the total length of the return value as it is displayed on your terminal screen. do you get any difference if you try `RPAD(CAST('甲骨文' AS NVARCHAR2(10)), 10, '$'), RPAD(CAST('甲骨文' AS VARCHAR2(10)), 10, '$')`?

Comment: It's not the case of "甲骨文$$$$$$$", 'cause AL32UTF8 is MULTI-BYTES character set. The method you provided return the same results like I posted above.

Comment: What if you put the explicit "N" in front of the literal:     N'甲骨文'

Comment: Hi @Morbo , adding an N before '甲骨文' seems to force ALL characters to take 2 bytes for each. The same result returned: 甲骨文$$$$ (Means that RPAD still consider one Chinese character as 2 bytes. The lengthb function now consider the same as RPAD, except the normal character, such as English character 'A' still be considered to take 2 bytes

Comment: Maybe RPAD expects both the source text and the addition text to be in the same encoding and maybe it is casting the source text into 8-bit to match the addition text in order to calculate the number of extra characters (clutching at straws here !). What if you put an "N" before the `'$'` too ?

Comment: Hi guys, I've got the reason and workarounds by searching from Google. Here is the explanation from Oracle documentation: "The total length of the return value as it is displayed on your terminal screen. In most character sets, this is also the number of characters in the return value. However, in some multibyte character sets, the display length of a character string can differ from the number of characters in the string." And workarounds depend on the actual display length in your screen (View text in monospaced fonts)

Comment: Workarounds: 1) SELECT RPAD('甲骨文', 10 - LENGTHC('甲骨文'), '$') FROM DUAL; 2) SELECT SUBSTRB('甲骨文' || RPAD('$', 10, '$'), 1, 10) FROM DUAL;

Comment: @eliuhy Can you post your comments as an answer?  That will help other people quickly understand the issue without having to read through the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the request of @jonearles , I copyed my solution on comment section as single answer here to help people to solve this problem.

> Hi guys, I've got the reason and workarounds by searching from Google. Here is the explanation from Oracle documentation: "The total length of the return value as it is displayed on your terminal screen. In most character sets, this is also the number of characters in the return value. However, in some multibyte character sets, the display length of a character string can differ from the number of characters in the string." And workarounds depend on the actual display length in your screen (View text in monospaced fonts)

**Workarounds**

```
-- 1) 
SELECT RPAD('甲骨文', 10 - LENGTHC('甲骨文'), '$') FROM DUAL; 
-- 2) Recomended!
SELECT SUBSTRB('甲骨文' || RPAD('$', 10, '$'), 1, 10) FROM DUAL;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is Oracle bug. The reason for a bug is: 
Every $ is one byte but every Chinese character is 3 bytes. When RPAD in this version is working he simply calculates 3 Chinese + 10 $'s = 13 bytes. When he displays 13 bytes - he has to cut some $'s. You welcome to open bug with Oracle.